# Is $f=0$ in $L^1$ if it were $0$ if it were in $L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^1([0,1])$ such that
$$\int_0^1 f(x) \exp(2 \pi i n x) dx=0$$
for all $n \in \mathbb Z$. Does this imply $f=0$?

If we would additionally know that $f \in L^2([0,1])$ this would be obvious since the functions $\exp(2 \pi i n x)$ are a Hilbert basis of the Hilbert space $L^2$. But since we only know $f \in L^1([0,1])$ I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: Yes because continuous functions are dense

Comment: @Conrad Can you explain your argument a little bit more? I know that continuous functions are dense in $L^1$ and in $L^2$ but how do you continue? Approximate $f$ by continuous functions? And then?

Comment: added a proof (actually simpler than using the density of continuous functions as those proofs are a bit more complicated and involve summability and other stuff like the fact that almost every point on $[0,1]$ of an integrable function is a Lebesgue point, where one actually uses the density of continous functions )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is the way Lebesgue did it a long time ago; one first shows the result for continuous functions (eg using the $L^2$ arguments or Feijer theorem - both may be actually post-Lebesgue and there are direct proofs too).

Then consider $F(x)=\int_{0}^xf(t)dt$; by general theory $F$ is absolutely continuous (hence differentiable ae) and $F'=f$ ae.

But $F(1)=F(0)=0$ by the hypothesis with $n=0$ and then for $|n| \ge 1$, integrating by parts one has

$\int_0^1 F(x) \exp(2 \pi i n x) dx=(F(1)-F(0))/(2\pi in)-\frac{1}{2\pi i n}\int_0^1 f(x) \exp(2 \pi i n x) dx=0$, so if $A=\int_0^1F(x)dx$ one has by the above result for continuous functions that $F(x)-A=0$ and by differentiating one gets that $f(x)=0$ ae