# Properties of $L^1([0,1]) \to \ell^\infty(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-series, lp-spaces

I want to learn more about the map
$$\varphi: L^1([0,1]) \to \ell^\infty(\mathbb Z),
\quad
\varphi(f)_n = \int_0^1 f(x) \exp(-2\pi nix) dx.
$$
It is linear and continuous since we have $||\varphi(f)||_{\infty} \le ||f||_1$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316267/is-f-0-in-l1-if-it-were-0-if-it-were-in-l2) I learnt that it is injective. Is it an isometry? What does the cokernel look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an isometry.  Consider, for example,
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=-N}^N \exp(2\pi i n x) = \frac{\sin((2N+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)} ,$$
where the right hand side comes from summing the geometric series.  Then it can be shown that ${\|f\|}_1$ is of the order of $\log N$, but clearly ${\| \varphi (f)\|}_\infty = 1$.

By the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma, we can see that $\varphi(f) \in c_0(\mathbb Z)$, and it is easily seen that the range of $\varphi$ is dense in $c_0(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! To use Riemann-Lebesgue in this situation you would extend $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb C$ to $\tilde f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ by setting it $f(x)=0$ for $x \notin [0,1]$, right? And your density statement is meant with respect to the norm in $\ell^\infty$?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: Then I'm very interested in the density statement. How do you prove that?

Comment: If $a = (a_n) \in c_0(\mathbb Z)$, and  $f_N(x) = \sum_{n=-N}^N a_n \exp(2\pi i N)$, then $\varphi(f_N) \to a$.

Comment: Oh, that's easy. Thanks a lot. You mean $\exp(2 \pi i n x)$ there.

Comment: Is the dimension of the cokernal infinite in $c_0(\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: It is very infinite dimensional.  $c_0(\mathbb Z)$ is separable, but $l^\infty(\mathbb Z)$ isn't.

Comment: No, no. I mean the image of $\varphi$ in $c_0(\mathbb Z)$. By what we developed so far it's not even clear that $\varphi$ is not surjective.

Comment: If you use the open mapping theorem, you will see that it cannot be surjective.  With a little more work, you can see that the cokernal is infinite dimensional.